# Were the rules of waqf (stopping) in the Qur'an since the beginning or were they developed through stages?

Tags: quran, tafseer, uloom-al-quran, tajweed

I had to ask this question because exegists are in disagreement about the waqf in the verse 7 of chapter 3 whether the waqf is after "الا للہ" or "والراسخون فی العلم". The slight shifting of this waqf changes the meaning of ayah altogether. I have read tafseer of Ibn Kathir in which he tried to explain that may be this is due to different understanding of word "تاویل" leading the scholars towards different opinions. So were the rules of stopping developed later? Are there other similar instances in the Qur'an as well?

Comment: The rules of waqf similar to the verse count are a topic of ijtihad and they are based on reports showing that the prophet used to stop at the end of a verse.